# Registration Process in XMPP Chat for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmpp

I am implementing a XMPP client for my iPhone App, I ahve completed all the things in (Chatting with other users , showing presence of other users , etc.)

But the one thing for which I am stuck is that , I am unable to get the new user registered from my App. I am using following snippet,

```
if ([appDelegate.xmppStream supportsInBandRegistration])
        [appDelegate.xmppStream registerWithPassword:txt_Password.text error:nil];
```

But for this, **supportsInBandRegistration** method always returns **NO** and the **registerWithPassword:** method is never called.

Please provide some help regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What server are you using?  Some servers support in-band registration even thought they don't send the correct stream:feature according to [XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html).  Most of them should give the feature in the disco results however.

In other words, try commenting out your `if ([appDelegate.xmppStream supportsInBandRegistration])` and see if it works.  If so, you'll need to complain either to your library developer or to your server developer or both.

Comment: I have tried for that also, but that is not the case as android version of that app is able to register. The  thing which I have realized is that, I am not using the correct procedure for Registration using **XEP-0077** ,I am not able to create the stream before calling these methods.